# Sorting List<T> in Java

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Job {
    private int priority;
    private String name;

    public int getPriority() { 
        return priority; 
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) { 
        this.priority = priority; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name; 
    }

    public void setName(Stirng name) { 
        this.name= name; 
    }
}
```

and I created some collection of it in the below variable:

```
List<Job> _jobs = ...
```

How can I sort the list by priority? (top of the list would be the highest priority value)

I found some reference in the internet but could not find a similar example.

Comment: Errr ... how long did you search? At least on my end, "java sort list property"  gives that existing question right there as first link ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortes way would be to use the sort method on the list itself, but this requires a mutable list:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Job::getPriority))
```

In case you have an immutable list, you may use streams for that:

```
List<Job> sortedList = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Job::getPriority)).collect(toList());
```

In case you're running on a JDK pre 1.8 use the sort method of the Collections class (requires a mutable list):

```
 Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Job>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(final Job o1, final Job o2) {

            return o1.getPriority()-o2.getPriority();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you use Java 8, please don't use `Collections.sort` but `List.sort` as shown in the first example.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Do you mean in all cases? Because `List.sort` doesn't have the option of using natural ordering

Comment: thanks, will try this

Comment: What? Yes it does: `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());`!

Comment: why is that the sort method does not appear when I type _job.sort?

Comment: you probably run on a JDK < 1.8

Comment: :( is there other way around?

Comment: it seems to work but how can make the highest priority be on top of the list?

Comment: just reverse the order in the comparison (o2-o1 instead of o1-o2)

Comment: it works! gracias!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda:

```
    _jobs.sort((a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.getPriority(), b.getPriority()));
    System.out.println(_jobs);
```